# How to SUM four parameter values

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have four parameters in one of my SSRS reports and want to have the summed result of all four parameters values displayed in a textbox.

I added the expression below in a textbox but it doesn’t work for me.

How do I get this to work?

Thanks,

```
Textbox5 = expression 

'=sum(Parameters!Parameter1.Value) + sum(Parameters!Parameter2.Value) + 
sum(Parameters!Parameter3.Value) + sum(Parameters!Parameter4.Value)'
```

Error Message:

> The Value expression for the text box 'Textbox5' uses an aggregate
>   expression without a scope. A scope is required for all aggregates
>   used outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one
>   dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is because you're attempting to `SUM` something that isn't summable. The expression you need is:

```
= Parameters!Parameter1.Value + Parameters!Parameter2.Value + 
  Parameters!Parameter3.Value + Parameters!Parameter4.Value
```

In other words, you don't need `SUM`, you just need to add the parameters together.

Here's a very quick/rough and ready report I've thrown together that shows this adding the values from the parameters:

[image: Quick 'n dirty report showing summing parameters]

Comment: I changed the expression as you mentioned in your codes but the result was different. It just joined all parameters and the result become "10204080". I think In Microsoft Visual Studio (SSRS) we use  "+" sign to join two or more field values. It didn't work for me.

Comment: That (probably!) means that the data type for the parameters is set to *Text* rather than *Integer* so the `+` operator is concatenating the strings together rather than adding the numbers together. You'll either need to change the Data type for the parameters, or convert the parameters to Integers, e.g. `CInt(Parameters!Parameter1.Value) + …….` (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/data-types-in-expressions-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The data type and the parameters were set to TEXT. After I changed them to Integer, now it works perfectly. I am really happy to join stack over flow community. Thank you